# Ember tests: How can I pause a test until some content is rendered?

Tags: testing, ember.js

I'm trying to create a simple test for creating of new record.

```
test('Create dataset', function(assert) {
  expect(1);
  visit('/add');

  fillIn('input.name', 'some name');
  fillIn('input.description', 'some description');


  //this part is to click on custom dropdown and select first option
  click('.select2-container input'); //after this action a list of options is generated
  click('.select2-drop ul li:first'); //but this action runs before the list was generated, so it gives me an error that this element does not exist

  click('button[type="submit"]');

});
```

Is there any way to pause the test untill the list as rendered?

For example something like waitFor('.select2-drop ul li:first')

UPD: I found out that select2 generated its dropdown list into 'body'. Ember tests are run in div#ember-testing. That is why my test script does not see content of select2.

Comment: Ember.run.later(function() {
            // try here after 5 sec
        }, 5000);

Comment: `andThen(() => click('.select2-drop ul li:first'));` should do the trick

Answer (score 2):

To handle async behaviours, use the [`andThen`](http://guides.emberjs.com/v1.10.0/testing/test-helpers/#toc_wait-helpers) helper

```
test('Create dataset', function(assert) {
  expect(1);
  visit('/add');

  andThen(function() {
    fillIn('input.name', 'some name');
    fillIn('input.description', 'some description');


    //this part is to click on custom dropdown and select first option
    click('.select2-container input'); //after this action a list of options is generated
    click('.select2-drop ul li:first'); //but this action runs before the list was generated, so it gives me an error that this element does not exist

    click('button[type="submit"]');
  });

});
```